# Joomla Form to External Script

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

I am coding a small script in PHP for users to be able to enquire about images they have in their lightbox using a Joomla plugin. However, because I have no idea how to create a Joomla plugin and need to roll out this functionality quickly I have created the script outside of Joomla and have just included it where I need it.

Below is the script I have coded (not yet finished).

```
<?php

    /*
        SETUP SCRIPT WITH JOOMLA SETTINGS
    */

    include('../configuration.php');
    $getConf = new JConfig();

    $config = array(
        'script_url' => '/custom/gallery.php',
        'url' => 'index.php/home/k2-tags/gallery/my-favorites',
        'current_state' => $_GET['state'],

        'host' => $getConf->host,
        'table' => $getConf->db,
        'user' => $getConf->user,
        'pass' => $getConf->password,
        'db_prefix' => $getConf->dbprefix,

        'user_id' => $user->id, // OBTAINED FROM INCLUDER PAGE IN JOOMLA

        'tb_joomla_users' => $getConf->dbprefix . 'users',
        'tb_datso_favorites' => $getConf->dbprefix . 'datsogallery_favorites',
        'tb_datso_master' => $getConf->dbprefix . 'datsogallery'
    );

    echo '<div id="datsocustom">';

    // ADD THE EMPTY GALLERY BUTTON
    //echo '<a href="' . $config['url'] . '"><button style="float:left;">EMPTY GALLERY</button></a>';

    // CHECK WHAT STATE THE SCRIPT IS IN AND ACT ACCORDINGLY
    if($config['current_state'] == '')
    {
        // Show button if state is default
        echo '<a href="' . $config['url'] . '?state=processing"><button style="float:right;">SEND ENQUIRY</button></a>';
        echo '<div style="clear:both;"></div>';
    }
    elseif($config['current_state'] == 'processing')
    {
        // Show ordering form if button is clicked
        if(isset($_POST['order_form'])){
            require('mysqli.php');
            $db = new DB($config);
        }

        echo "<p>Listed below are copies of all the images that you currently have in your gallery. if you'd like us to check the availability of these images please enter the product type and territory.</p>";
        echo "<p>These details will then be emailed to us directly and we will reply as soon as we can with the availability information.</p>";

        echo '<form method="post" action="' . $config['url'] . '?state=processing" style="padding:10px;">';

        echo '<label>Please enter any notes about the nature of your enquiry</label><br />';
        echo '<textarea name="enquiry_info" id="enquiry_info" style="width:100%; height:150px; padding:5px; border:1px solid #CCC; font-size:12px;"></textarea><br />';

        echo '<label>To help us check availability please specify the kind of usage you need for the images in this enquiry</label><br />';
        echo '<label>Product List</label>';
        echo '<select>';
        echo '<option>Default</option>';
        echo '</select><br />';
        echo '<label>Territory</label>';
        echo '<select>';
        echo '<option>Default</option>';
        echo '</select><br />';

        echo '<button type="submit" style="float:right;" name="send_enquiry">SUBMIT ENQUIRY</button>';
        //echo '<input type="submit" style="float:right;" value="SUBMIT ENQUIRY" name="send_enquiry" />';

        echo '</form>';

        echo '<div style="clear:both;"></div>';
    }
    elseif($config['current_state'] == 'success')
    {
        // Show success message if order has processed
    }
    elseif($config['current_state'] == 'failed')
    {
        // Show error message if order has not been processed


        echo '<a href="' . $config['url'] . '"><button style="float:right;">TRY AGAIN</button></a>';
        echo '<div style="clear:both;"></div>';
    }
    elseif($config['current_state'] == 'empty_gallery')
    {

    }

    echo '</div>';
```

The main issue is that when I post the form within Joomla it sends the user to a the URL -> index.php/home/k2-tags/gallery instead of index.php/home/k2-tags/gallery/my-favorites?state=processing.

Does Joomla override forms by any chance? Because I think that is the problem. If anyone can give me any advice what so ever it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Don't put `?state=processing` in `action` attribute of the form.

Somewhere inside the form (preferably in the beginning or in the end) put:

```
echo '<input type="hidden" name="state" value="processing"/>'; // XHTML assummed
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment but this still does not let the form post correctly. I have tried this and it still sends me to the URL ending /gallery.

Comment: Is `action` attribute of the form set properly, when you view page source in the browser?

Comment: action="index.php/home/k2-tags/gallery/my-favorites" - Also shows ?state=processing when I add that too.

Comment: That's really strange - I suspect there must be redirection performed either by web server or Joomla. Try Live Http Headers extension under Firefox to track if there is 301 or 302 redirection.

Comment: I'll giv that a go now. It is strange. I did originally thing it was a Joomla redirection.